# How to seperate Array in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i just learn about haskell
but i've problem about Type Data, ihave type data like below

```
[Test {name = "name1", Address = "Address1", Score = 80},Test {name = "name2", Address = "Address2", Score = 60}]
```

my question is how to seperate to =

```
Name  Address  Score Pass
-------------------------
name1 Address1 80    Y
name2 Address2 60    N
```

i've try

```
printArray :: [Test] -> IO()
printArray [Test x y z]  = do
                                putStr x
                                putStr (" " ++ y)
                                putStr (" " ++ show z)
                                if z >= 70 then putStrLn " Y"
                                else putStrLn " N"
```

but when i executed i got error : Non-exhaustive patterns in function printArray

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any arrays here. `[]` is for *lists*.

The reason your code with `printArray [Test x y z] = ...` doesn't do the trick is that it only matches the case of a list with *exactly one element* in it. If you want to do this for *all* elements you can use either

- Recursion.

  ```
  printTests (Test x y z : tests) = do
                putStr x
                putStr (" " ++ y)
                putStr (" " ++ show z)
                putStrLn $ if z >= 70 then " Y"
                                      else " N"
                printTests tests
  printTests [] = return ()
  ```
- [A standard looping combinator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_)

  ```
  printTests = mapM_ $ \(Test x y z) -> do
                 ...
  ```
- ...or, perhaps easier to understand

  ```
  import Control.Monad (forM_)

  printTests tests = forM_ tests $ \(Test x y z) -> do
                 ...
  ```
- **(Recommended)** Separate your concerns: instead of doing nasty IO in a loop setting, start with simple

  ```
  showTest :: Test -> String
  ```

  And then use `putStrLn (unlines $ map showTest tests)` where printing actually is needed.

Comment: thanks in advance its works!

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. You pattern-match the singleton list containing just one element [Test x y z].

```
printArray :: [Test] -> IO ()
printArray []  = pure ()
printArray (Test x y z : xs)  = do
  putStr x
  putStr (" " ++ y)
  putStr (" " ++ show z)
  if z >= 60
    then putStrLn " Y"
    else putStrLn " N"
  printArray xs
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it:

```hs
printTest :: Test -> IO()
printTest (Test x y z) = do
  putStr x
  putStr (" " ++ y)
  putStr (" " ++ show z)
  if z >= 60
    then putStrLn " Y"
    else putStrLn " N"

printArray :: [Test] -> IO()
printArray [] = pure ()
printArray (t:ts) = do
    printTest t
    printArray ts
```